# For loop is only checking last value

Tags: java, list, authentication

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I can't seem to find much help for it. So I'm designing a login using vaadin and a h2 in mem SQL database. There is a method that returns the values from the database in a list. The trouble is that I'm having problems with the method below. It's meant to iterate through every entry in the list and if it finds a username / password that matches then return true. If not return false.....

```
public boolean checkUserInDatabase(String username, String email) {
    boolean result = false;
    List<User> localArray = getUserList();

    System.out.println("List retrieved...Checking user in database"+ 
localArray);
    for (User u : localArray ) {
        if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            result = true;
        }
        else {

            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm aware that at this point I'm only checking the username however, when I add users to the database it will still only check the last user in that database....thoughts?

Comment: It _will_ check all users but `result` contains only the result of the last check when you return it - because you always overwrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is purely logical. You are iterating through your list, and only **at the end** returning the value. So your program is going through the entire list, and provides only the last result. Here is your complete, correct program:

```
public boolean checkUserInDatabase(String username, String email) {
    boolean result = false;
    List<User> localArray = getUserList();

    System.out.println("List retrieved...Checking user in database"+ localArray);
    for (User u : localArray ) {
        if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
        return true;
        }
    }

return result;
}
```

This way if your program finds a user it directly answers `true` instead of going through the rest of the list.

Answer (score 7):

You are checking every value, but you retrieve it from the last one. You basically need an exit condition which you already have. Change your code to this

```
public boolean checkUserInDatabase(String username, String email) {
    List<User> localArray = getUserList();
    for (User u: localArray) {
        if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Now you also change the method to have multiple-point-of-return instead of single-point-of-return. I would recommend to keep single-point-of-return by introducing a break-statement.

Comment: @MathiasBader Not sure what you mean, but there is only one return.

Comment: I think he means that your code has two distincts points of `return`: in the `for` loop, and outside. His recommandation was to keep the allocation of `userFound` and break the loop, thus returning `userFound` only at the end of the method 'visually'. I agree that it does not bring that much, tho.

Comment: Exactly @YassineBadache. The discussion which way is better is one thing.  I just think the solution should reflect the choice the OP made and should not choose a different paradigm without reasoning about why the change was made.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely return the boolean once you found the user.

```
if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going through the entire list and resetting the return value every time so the last one is the only one which matters.  You need something like:

```
boolean userFound = false;
for (User u : localArray ) 
{
    if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) 
    {
        userFound = true;
        break;
    }
 }

return userFound ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to return the value at the last line is actually good - it's the principle of [single-point-of-return](https://hackerchick.com/religious-war-48293-single-vs-multiple/) and I would recommend to do that. It makes debugging easier. So the solution would be like:

```
public boolean checkUserInDatabase(String username, String email) {
    boolean result = false;
    List<User> localArray = getUserList();

    System.out.println("List retrieved...Checking user in database" + localArray);
    for (User u : localArray ) {
        if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }  else {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Though it should be mentioned that there are different schools of thought. I personally prefer single-point-of-return, but arguments can be found for both.

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 solution would be to avoid the for loop entirely and simply say:

```
boolean userFound = collection.stream()
    .map(User::getUsername)
    .anyMatch(n -> n.equals(username))
```